# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for passing Date and Time value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm currently working on a JSP Web application and I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on the line with `timeRequested = new Date(xDate);`.

Everything seems right and I don't know where I'm going wrong; any help would be much appreciated. I'm storing the attribute from the Date textbox into a field in my database.

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    PreOrder preMe = (PreOrder) session.getAttribute("preOrderObj");
    User useMe = (User) session.getAttribute("userObj");
    Venue venueMe = (Venue) session.getAttribute("venueObj");

   //Date expiredDate = new Date();
    String xuserId = useMe.getUserId() + "";
    // int userId = Integer.parseInt(xuserId);        
    String xquantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
    //int quantity = Integer.parseInt(xquantity);  

    int userId = 0;
    if (xuserId != null) {
        userId = Integer.parseInt(xuserId);
    }
    int quantity = 0;
    if (xquantity != null) {
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(xquantity);
    }

    if (session.getId() != session.getAttribute("clientLoggedInId")) {

        forwardToJsp = "404.jsp";
    } else {
        try {

            PreOrderDao preDao = new PreOrderDao();
            VenueDao venueD = new VenueDao();
            Venue venueName = venueD.findVenue("venueD");

            DrinksDao drinkD = new DrinksDao();
            Drinks drinkName = drinkD.findDrink("drinkName");

            Date timeRequested = new Date();

            String xDate = request.getParameter("timeRequested");
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            timeRequested = new Date(xDate);
            dateFormat.format(xDate);

           //      timeRequested = sdf.parse(xDate);
            PreOrder ord1 = new PreOrder(venueName, drinkName, quantity, timeRequested);
            session.setAttribute("preOrderObj", ord1);
            preDao.placeOrder(ord1);

        } catch (DaoException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(UserActionServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        forwardToJsp = "form2.jsp";
    }
    return forwardToJsp;
}
```

}

Comment: `String xDate = request.getParameter("timeRequested");` print value in xDate variable to see what is going

Comment: its printing out null ?

Comment: which means that there is no such variable in request?

Comment: String xDate = request.getParameter("timeRequested");
           Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(xDate);
            timeRequested = newDate;

Comment: Now it says i have an unparseable date??

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
timeRequested = new Date(xDate);
dateFormat.format(xDate);
```

to this:

```
timeRequested = dateFormat.parse(xDate);
```